# Sencha-touch localization. Use a store or a global JSON object?

Tags: json, localization, sencha-touch

I'm writting an application in Sencha-Touch 1.1 and I want to add localization to strings.

I've thought (but not implemented) of two ways.

1. Create seperate JSON files for each language (en-US.json, el-GR.json
   etc) and use a **proxy** and a **store** to load the data, changing each
   time the proxy url (json file destination). The problem is that I don't know how to extract the data from the store afterwards.
2. Create a global JSON object which then I inflate (parse the json file
   and turn it into an object). The problem here is that I cannot seem to find a way to parse a JSON file without using a reader/proxy combo.

Is there any optimal solution for localizing strings in sencha-touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach is to extract all of your strings into class level properties and have separate locale files which override these classes and their string properties.

For example, if I had a panel like this:

```
MyApp.MyPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {

    myPanelContent: 'This is your text to be translated...',

    initComponent: function(){

        Ext.apply(this, {
            html: this.myPanelContent
        });

         MyApp.MyPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this)
    }

});
```

And then you would have a locale file along the lines of:

```
Ext.override(MyApp.MyPanel, {

    myPanelContent: 'This is a translation of my text to another language'

});
```

You can then either load the correct locale file when your app is loaded (after the views themselves have been loaded) or dynamically load the locale files during runtime (this would require logic to update each of the views with the current value).

Hope this makes sense, give me a shout if it doesn't!

Stuart

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the two ways of loading the correct locale? If I add it to my index.html, the locale changes automatically..

Comment: Yes, if you add it to your index.html that will mean the included locale is your default. You load a new one dynamically creating a new <script> tag and pointing it to the desired JS file. You will also need to incorporate some kind of callback (ala JSONP) so you can react to the locale file loading and update your views with the new text.